# Framer motion start animation after another animation end

Tags: next.js, framer-motion

how can I start animation after another animation end with framer motion

```
<motion.div
   variants={variants1}
   initial="hidden"
   animate={controls} 
   ref={element} 
>
   Start animation one             
</motion.div>


<motion.div
   variants={variants2}
   initial="hidden"
   animate={controls} 
   ref={element} 
>
   Start animation Two
</motion.div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `staggerChildren` transition property of framer-motion to delay each child's animation. So this way the N child's animation will start after the N - 1 child's animation.

```js
import { motion, Variants } from "framer-motion";
import "./styles.css";

/**
   * Here we are defining @param staggerChildren with 1sec.
   * You can change this time as per your need.
   * 1st child will not get delayed. Delay starts from 2nd child onwards.
   * 2nd child animation will start after: 1sec
   * 3rd child animation will start after: 2sec
   * 4th child animation will start after: 3sec
   * and so on...
   */
const parentVariant: Variants = {
  initial: { opacity: 0 },
  animate: { opacity: 1, transition: { staggerChildren: 1 } }
};

const childrenVariant: Variants = {
  initial: { opacity: 0, x: 50 },
  animate: { opacity: 1, x: 0 }
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <motion.div initial="initial" animate="animate" variants={parentVariant}>
        <motion.div className="child" variants={childrenVariant}>
          Start animation One
        </motion.div>
        <motion.div className="child" variants={childrenVariant}>
          Start animation Two
        </motion.div>
        <motion.div className="child" variants={childrenVariant}>
          Start animation Three
        </motion.div>
        <motion.div className="child" variants={childrenVariant}>
          Start animation Four
        </motion.div>
      </motion.div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Note that we are not defining `initial` and `animate` labels for children because these labels can flow from parent to child, hence they will be inherited automatically by the children.

Here is a CodeSandbox example: https://codesandbox.io/embed/framer-motion-staggerchildren-nxfrnb?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark